# Database structure help needed

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an app where you can review a product from different stores, the app will only have one review per store, and I will include the local review and the product reviewed, also you have to enter both reviews, you can't have a store without a product reviewed.

My question is, should I have in tables separates (product, store) or together in one called (review)

I have this alredy:

```
store ['uuid', 'name', 'rrss', 'address', 'picture', 'exterior', 'toppings', 'decorationScore', 'crowdedScore', 'priceScore', 'review']

product ['uuid', 'picture', 'price', 'textureScore', 'tasteScore', 'review', 'storeId']
```

Comment: 1 `product` can have many `stores`, and 1 `store` can have many `products` => the solution is an additional table with pk from `product` and `store` tables, and additional attributes related to this relationship (price, date, etc...) If you have this kind of questions, I recommend you to read normalization in sql before starting to think in some app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you have separate tables for each entity:

- shop
- product
- review, which has foreign key references to the above

You can use constraints to limit one review per shop/user and product/user.

Why?  First, this "naturally" fits your data.  More importantly, you may change or relax your limitations over time.  For instance:

- Reviews might be "replaced" or "updated" and you might want to keep a history of the reviews.
- You might allow more than one review at a given time.

Comment: Imagine only the admin can review the store and his product, also I have no users in the app, people can only read the reviews, u would still use the same approach?